# How do you find the sourcemap URL or its contents for a given script in javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, source-maps

If I have the url of a script that has a sourcemap, is there an easy way to find the sourcemap url for it (or the sourcemap contents)? Basically, I want to get the source map so I can use it with https://github.com/mozilla/source-map

Comment: Request the same script with a `.map` extension instead of `.js`?

Comment: I don't want to resort to hacks. If I was going to resort to anything, it'd be a regex match on the script - but even that fails if the script uses a header instead of the weird comment thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh kay, so I got impatient and wrote a library for this:

https://github.com/fresheneesz/sourcemap-locator

Example usage:

`var sourcemapUrl = sourcemapLocator.fromUrl(originalSourceUrl)`